# Cut off graphs using dot2texi with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, org-mode, dot2texi

I am creating concept maps using `dot2texi` and `TiKz`. However, with more complex maps the current style sometimes causes the map to be cut off. This despite the fact that in theory there is actually enough space left. I read the `dot2texi` and the `TikZ` manual, but I am still in the dark about how this can be automatically adjusted. This is very important to me: I don't want to adjust the graphs manually. For they are the result of an `org-mode` source block: cf. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316986/creating-concept-map-akin-to-markdown/317240#317240)

Here is an example of a map that is cut off on the right hand side:

[image: Cut off map]

And here is the relevant `LaTeX` source code as created by `Org-mode` `LaTeX` export:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.8in,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\section{Chapter 3}


\begin{center}

\begin{dot2tex}[scale=0.8, tikz, options={-t raw --tikzedgelabel --nodeoptions='every node/.style={text width=2cm, text centered, rounded corners, fill=black!10}' --edgeoptions="every node/.style={fill=white, inner sep=1pt}"}]


digraph G {

node [shape=box];

"Chapter 3" -> "general jurisdiction" [label="has", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];
"Chapter 3" -> "special jurisdiction" [label="has", lblstyle="pos=0.35"]; 
"Chapter 3" -> "particular issues" [label="has", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];

"special jurisdiction" -> "tort" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];
"special jurisdiction" -> "contract" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"]; 
"special jurisdiction" -> "exclusive jurisdiction" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];
"special jurisdiction" -> "submission" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];


"special jurisdiction" -> "multiple defendants" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];

"special jurisdiction" -> "presence" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];

"presence" -> "branch, ageny or other establishment" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];


"contract" -> "general contract" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];
"contract" -> "special contracts" [label="is", lblstyle="pos=0.35"]; 

"special contracts" -> "consumer contracts" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];
"special contracts" -> "employment contract" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];


"submission" -> "regular submission" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];
"submission" -> "choice of court agreements" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];


"particular issues" -> "anti-suit injunctions" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];
"particular issues" -> "forum non conveniens" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"]; 
"particular issues" -> "freezing injunctions" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];


"particular issues" -> "reform of Brussels regulation" [label="can be", lblstyle="pos=0.35"];


}


\end{dot2tex}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The example concept map I used seems to be misleading as it suggests that every concept map will or should look like a top-down tree. This may be the case, but need to. Here is a more complex example, which shows that there can be several connections between nodes on different levels/branches. This new example is cut off, too. For demonstration purposes I merely changed the paper size to A3 and then took a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please, remove all unnecessary packages? Compiling with pdfLaTeX gives empty page ...

Comment: @Zarko: I removed some packages that may be unnecessary. Unfortunately, you are correct. There are only two "empty" packages, because the `dot`file is not converted. Before posting my question, it worked. I have to look into the issue. Thanks so far!

Comment: You still haw twice 7inputenc` and `fontenc`. I also daubt that for diagram is `titlesec` necessary. For test purposes you can add option `showframe` to `geometry` package. It seems that sibling distance in second level of tree is to big.

Comment: @Zarko: the unedited MWE works, but you have to use `pdflatex`with the option `-shell-escape` as `dot2texi` has to run `graphviz`. Notice that I removed the `sibling distance=2cm` and `level distance=2cm` from the options. Decreasing or increasing these values seems to have no visual effect, neither positive nor negative. I do see why the cut off happens. `dot2texi` keeps a constant distance between the nodes on the second level. As the node `special jurisdiction` gets very broad on the third level, the node `particular issues` is moved to the far right, to keep in line with 2nd level.

Comment: It would be beneficial, if `dot2texi` would allow that nodes on the same level are not aligned horizontally. `special jurisdiction` could move down and make room for `particular issues`. Concept maps don't have to look like clean trees, so this would be ok.

Comment: To me is simpler to rewrite your tree directly in `tikz` even with `forest` (which I still learn) that learn `dot2texi` package or change settings of my editor :-). If in reasonable time you will not receive adequate help, consider this possibilities.

Comment: Another possibility similar to what @Zarko is suggesting, is to exploit the layout capabilities of PGF3 graphs, which even support a syntax that is extremely similar to dot's so it would require very little adjustment of the generation from the org-mode

Comment: What do you mean when you say that in theory there's enough space left? What theory?

Comment: @cfr, in the first concept map you see that the node 'particular issues' and its subnodes would probably fit on the page. For example, under the node 'branch, agency or other establishment'. This is what I would do, if I were draw the map by hand. And this is because I know that it is not required that nodes on the same levels must be aligned on that same level. A proposition `TiKz` seems to adhere to.

Comment: @SingulaereEntitaet It isn't TikZ. It is the algorithm being used to layout the tree or graph. Forest uses TikZ and does not adhere to that rule by default. Similarly, the graph drawing algorithms TikZ provides are many and various. I assume that `dot2tex` must be using an algorithm which does this. TikZ isn't laying out the graph in this case at all, as can be seen from the generated `.tex` file which positions everything manually.